# How do I access workspace areas in 2.80 with Python

Tags: python, scripting, workspaces

In a previous script I made for 2.79 I could change properties on a particular layout area without having it active:

```
for area in bpy.data.screens["Animation"].areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for spaces in area.spaces:
            if spaces.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                area.spaces.active.clip_start = 0.1
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this with 2.80 and workspaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to iceythe from blenderartists:
https://blenderartists.org/t/access-to-workspace-areas/1137024

```
for area in bpy.data.workspaces['my_workspace'].screens[0].areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
      for spaces in area.spaces:
          if spaces.type == 'VIEW_3D':
              area.spaces.active.clip_start = 0.1
```